# Counter - write to txt file

Tags: vbscript

Do you give in to the counter:

```
Function PadZeros(s, l)
  PadZeros = Right("00000000" & s, l)
End Function

Dim myFSO, Licznik_ID, txt, arr
Set myFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt").ReadAll
arr = split(txt, " ")
Licznik_ID = arr(UBound(arr))
txt = txt & " " & PadZeros(CInt(Licznik_ID)+1, 8)
myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt", 2, True).write (txt)
```

to do so that each digit of the counter has been saved, the latter the only one in txt file?

so instead of within 00001 00002 00003

it be possible to do this:

00003

or to remember the last digit of the final counting.

Is it possible to have in addition to writing down instead of to the right in order to create a CSV file?

Comment: PARSE_ERROR. Do you want the current counter to replace the previous one(s) or do you want it to be appended? You can't have both with a single file.

Comment: Yes. I want the current counter to replace the previous one

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
txt = txt & " " & PadZeros(CInt(Licznik_ID)+1, 8)
```

with this

```
txt = PadZeros(CInt(Licznik_ID)+1, 8)
```

`txt` contains the original contents of the text file. If you say `txt = txt &` then you're concatenating everything after the `&` to the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current counter to replace the previous counter(s): simply don't append the current counter to the previous counter(s).

```
filename = "C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'read ID from file
Licznik_ID = CInt(fso.OpenTextFile (filename).ReadAll)

Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1

'write incremented ID back to file
fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, True).Write Licznik_ID
```